# How to generate a meta code like xn * n / 10 which may be plus for more than ten times?

Tags: dolphindb

I write the meta code like `<wd_nBidPrice1*0.1 + wd_nBidPrice2*0.2 + wd_nBidPrice3*0.3 +...+wd_nBidPrice10*1.0>`, in which there are ten formulas with the same structure.

How to generate such meta code in a loop statement?

It will be very troublesome to write it manually if there are 100 formulas in this meta code. Can I generate this meta code in a statement such as `for (n in 1.. 100) {}`?

Answer (score 0):

The example code is as follows:

```py
script="wd_nBidPrice1*0.1 "
for(n in 2..10){
   script+="+ wd_nBidPrice"+ n + "*"+n\10 
}
parseExpr(script)
```

This is not meta programming. This is string concatenation.